# microsoft access goods web database adding to montly report

Tags: ms-access, form-fields

I downloaded the microsoft goods web database from microsoft's template library. [this is their link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Cut-expenses-manage-inventory-and-ship-effectively-by-using-the-Goods-web-database-template-DBA011E4-A432-4BBD-BECD-10CF02D7D76D) I was hoping to add onto the monthly reports my profit along side the sales, (or if necessary create a profit report, but that seemed way more complex).  in the monthlyclientsales report form there is a field  "=Nz(Sum([Total Sales]),0)" that calculates how much money was made that month by im assuming calculating what my sales were for the certain month.
What I was hoping was to have a 2nd field that would calculate profits by subtracting product sales price from the cost of purchase.  Both datafields are in the product table as "standard cost" and "list price" but I'm not sure how to translate that to the form field.

Answer (score 0):

You could add them to the form in the same way. Then name the controls. SumCost and SumSales
You can then add an unbound textbox called profit and set an expression of

`=SumSales-SumCost`

Comment: Thank you for replying Alex!  This is exactly what I want to do.  how can i add them to the form?

Comment: I take it there is a quantity field which will be that times list price to get [Total Sales], so Product Sales Price "=Nz(Sum([Total Sales]),0), Cost of Purchase "=Nz(Sum([Standard Cost]*Qty),0). Name those controls as above